# How to create a EditText with the top corner rounded and the bottom rectangle

Tags: android

I have a simple background in my drawable folder, just a border that I use on my EditText :

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

But I want to achieve [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/65/0a/bf/650abf858655ad1bc26408e1defd486c--interaction-design-android-apps.jpg).
Top rounded and the bottom rectangle in the edges! I'm having trouble and do this

Answer (score 2):

Create one `Drawable` shape xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <corners android:radius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

Set that `drawable` in you EditText background

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"
    android:background="@drawable/testing"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**create
round_shape.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                    android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
            
            </shape>
```

> Set that drawable in you Edit Text background

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/round_shape"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one work for me

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
    android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
```

please check and change radius.

Comment: Didn't work,the rounded area has to be in top of the EditText

Comment: @NathielPaulino please check my uppdate corner radious and try.

Answer (score 0):

here create editbox_custom_top_radius.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Here Corner use for give curve to your edit text-->
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>

    <!--stroke is use to apply border on edit text-->
    <stroke android:width="2dp"/>

    <!--solid for incase you want background color to edit box-->
    <solid android:color="@color/app_grey"/>
</shape>
```

create editbox_custom_bottom_radius.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Here Corner use for give curve to your edit text-->
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>

    <!--stroke is use to apply border on edit text-->
    <stroke android:width="2dp"/>

    <!--solid for incase you want background color to edit box-->
    <solid android:color="@color/app_grey"/>
</shape>
```

and apply it on your edit box

```
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_custom_top_radius"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"
        android:background="@drawable/editbox_custom_bottom_radius"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

try it.

Comment: i have refer your above link it some like https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/65/0a/bf/650abf858655ad1bc26408e1defd486c--interaction-design-android-apps.jpg above code